# How to Update integer column with Thousand Seperator as "." in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, format

Hi I have a table that with integer data type and have values like "1000" ,"10000" "1000000" and I want to convert them as "1.000" , "10.000" and "1.000.000". Also I want to keep them in integer format. Is that possible ?

Comment: Numbers are stored without any formatting. If you want to apply a specific format, do that when _displaying_ the values in your application. You can convert the integer to a formatted string using `to_char()` but SQL is really not the best place to apply such formatting

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot store an `integer` that way:

```
show lc_numeric; 
en_US.UTF-8  

select 10,000::integer; 
 ?column? | int4 
----------+------
       10 |    0

select 10.000::integer;
 int4 
------
   10

select to_char(10000, '99G999');
 to_char 
---------
  10,000

select to_number('10,000', '99G999');
 to_number 
-----------
      1000





set lc_numeric='de_DE.UTF-8';
SET

show lc_numeric ;
 lc_numeric  
-------------
 de_DE.UTF-8

select 10,000::integer;
 ?column? | int4 
----------+------
       10 |    0
(1 row)

select 10.000::integer;
 int4 
------
   10
(1 row)

select to_char(10000, '99G999');
 to_char 
---------
  10.000

select to_number('10.000', '99G999');
 to_number 
-----------
     10000
```

[lc_numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-NUMERIC):

> lc_numeric (string)

> Sets the locale to use for formatting numbers, for example with the to_char family of functions. Acceptable values are system-dependent; see Section 24.1 for more information. If this variable is set to the empty string (which is the default) then the value is inherited from the execution environment of the server in a system-dependent way.

So the only way locale specific information is going to be relevant is when you format the number to a string or vice versa.